# multiple cutsom cells in UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

Can anyone give me idea on how to define two custom cells in one UITableView? One cell should only contain text while the other contain video or image. The height also differs with each other. I need cells just like the given image below-

[image]

Here is the code am working on-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"tablecell";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"tablecell1";

    if ([self.arrayAction isEqual:@"follow"]) 
    {
        ActivityFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        [utilities roundedLayer:cell.sub_view.layer shadow:YES];
        [utilities AddBorder:cell.updated_imgView];

        cell.userName_label.text=[[[[[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@"("]stringByAppendingString:[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAppendingString:@")"];
        cell.descriptionImg_label.text=[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://tattoosingles.net/tattoouploads/%@",[_arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

       [cell.updated_imgView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
       [utilities AddBorder:cell.updated_imgView];

       cell.updated_imgView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
       cell.updated_imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
       cell.userProfile_imgView.layer.mask = [self ChangeShape:cell.userProfile_imgView];

       NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://tattoosingles.net/uploads/%@",[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"path"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

       [cell.userProfile_imgView sd_setImageWithURL:url1];

       return cell;
    } 
    else if ([self.arrayAction isEqual:@"tplike"])
    {
        ActivityFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        [utilities roundedLayer:cell.sub_view.layer shadow:YES];
        [utilities AddBorder:cell.updated_imgView];

        cell.userName_label.text=[[[[[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@"("]stringByAppendingString:[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAppendingString:@")"];
        cell.descriptionImg_label.text=[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://tattoosingles.net/tattoouploads/%@",[_arrayname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        [cell.updated_imgView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
        [utilities AddBorder:cell.updated_imgView];

        cell.updated_imgView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
        cell.updated_imgView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.userProfile_imgView.layer.mask = [self ChangeShape:cell.userProfile_imgView];

        NSURL *url1 = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://tattoosingles.net/uploads/%@",[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"path"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

        [cell.userProfile_imgView sd_setImageWithURL:url1];

        return cell;
    }
    else 
    {
        ActivityFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        cell.userName_label.text=[[[[[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:@"("]stringByAppendingString:[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]stringByAppendingString:@")"];
        cell.descriptionImg_label.text=[[_responseArray valueForKey:@"description"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        // Configure cell

        return cell;
    }
}
```

And here is the output am getting-

[image]

Comment: Please take note of the edits I made to your question. Your code was unreadable, please keep it formatted so others can answer your question

Comment: Okay. I will keep in mind!!

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create seperate .xib file for the same.

2) You can create prototype cell also for above two cell.

Comment: i have already done the second step but my code doesn't work right. Can you check my code above?

Comment: what you are getting from above code? show me resulted image which you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Create any number of custom cells you need, and create subclass for each like,

```
//typeA cell
class TypeATableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  // your custom properties and functions
}
//typeB cell
class TypeBTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  // your custom properties and functions
}
```

then in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** functions, you can return cell based on indexPath,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // here i used section to return different cell, but it can be anything
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TypeATableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TypeATableViewCell

        // your custom code
        return cell

    }else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TypeBTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TypeBTableViewCell

        // your custom code
        return cell
    }
}
```

for dynamic Height, you can use iOS 8 feature, **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**

check out this article to know how to implement dynamic sizing cells https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Answer (score 0):

You can do,like this:

**Step 1:** Create an empty **Xib** and put multiple cells in it.

**Step 2:** Customise cells according to your need and give each cell a unique **Identifier**.

**Step 3**: **Assign your custom class to each of these cells**.i.e if you have XYZ as your custom tableViewCell class then all these cells will have XYZ as their class.

**Step 4:** Now use that custom tableViewCell class for your tableView and **use identifier** to show different cells.

```
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"";//Use_Identifier_Here
NSInteger indexForCell = 0;
        indexForCell = [YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL nibIndexForIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell= (YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSString *strNib = @"YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL";
            NSArray *nib =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:strNib owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (YOUR_CUSTOM_CELL *)[nib objectAtIndex:indexForCell];
        }
```

**nibIndexForIdentifier:**

```
+(NSInteger )nibIndexForIdentifier:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{
    NSInteger nibIndex =0;
    if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_FIRST_CELL_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        nibIndex =0;
    }else if ([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SECOND_CELL_IDENTIFIER"]){
        nibIndex = 1;
    }

    return nibIndex;
}
```

Comment: Then you will have to create separate custom cell for your number of cells. By doing this also you will have to access them by using identifier. This approach will increase your number of files as well as you will have to code at different places which could be tedious to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with custom cell for table view more.It is very very easy.Even you have lot of custom cells.You can call that according to your sections title or cell.I will give you coding

First you need to set the height for cell

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[self.arrayAction objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"follow"])
       return 60;   //This is for Label text
   return 100;    //This is for image and video
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ActivityFeedCell *cell = (ActivityFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Reuse"];
   NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityFeedCell" owner:self options:nil];
   @try
   {
     if ([[self.arrayAction objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"follow"]] 
     {
        if(cell == nil)
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0;
        cell.userName_label.text=@""; //Your Value
        cell.descriptionImg_label.text=@"";//Your Value

     }
     else if ([[self.arrayAction objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"tplike"]] 
     {
        if(cell == nil)
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
        cell.updated_imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];//Your Image or Video
     }

    return cell;
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception);
  }
}
```

Comment: am facing error in this line--- NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityFeedCell" owner:self options:nil];     Can you tell me why?

Comment: You have to give your CustomCell Name.That is in Nib like CustomCell.xib or ActivityFeedCell.xib

Comment: is your custom cell name ' ActivityFeedCell'?

Comment: If you face any error,show me the error line or crash report.